# JS Cookie hide/show div

Tags: jquery, cookies, shopify

Trying to make a jQuery cookie hide/show box using [JS Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), but I somehow can't make it work. The box won't display at all. I'm using Shopify.

```
#pop-up {
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function(){
  // if no cookie
  if (!$.cookie('alert')) {
      $( "#pop-up" ).show();
      $("#hide").click(function() {
          $( "#pop-up" ).slideUp( "slow" );
          // set the cookie for 24 hours
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
          $.cookie('alert', true, { expires: date });
      });
  }
  });//]]> 
</script>
```

The rest:

```
<div id="pop-up">
  <div id="center" class="box">
    40% off today only<br>
    <a id="hide" href="#">OK, thanks!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work because you can only store **strings** in cookies. You store the string `"true"` instead of the boolean value `true`.

Try the following code where I replaced the check with `!= "true"`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function(){
  // if no cookie
  if ($.cookie('alert')!="true") {
      $( "#pop-up" ).show();
      $("#hide").click(function() {
          $( "#pop-up" ).slideUp( "slow" );
          // set the cookie for 24 hours
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
          $.cookie('alert', "true", { expires: date });
      });
  }
  });//]]> 
</script>
```

A working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqam0qb4/1/

Comment: Thanks! But it still won't work. The box won't display. Is there something wrong with the way I outputted  JS Cookie?

`<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0437/4361/t/9/assets/jquery.cookie.js?3749616718764010363" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Thanks @Bas van Stein ! Works great with reset cookies.